# How to lift the corner of a heavy stove with a bottle jack

Tags: kitchens, foundation, appliances

So I have a very heavy stove that I need to lift one corner of (to slip back in a floor protector disc that slipped out) and it's too heavy for one person to budge.  I think it's 350 lbs.

I have a bottle jack that I'm trying to figure out if I can use, but I don't see any reachable hardpoints to get under and only spots where I'd have to cantilever a clip or something to.  The stove bottom is only an inch off the ground so I can't get underneath it.  The hardpoints are either too low for the jack, or something I can't reach with the jack since I'd have to open the oven door.  There are some small slits that I can get a small flat piece of something into perhaps, like in the horizontal grille between the door top and the controls.

Any suggestions for a simple jury rig I can do to lift up the corner of the stove with a simple part or something I can fashion from around the house? (I don't have to move the stove if that makes things easier).

[image]

Comment: Can you lighten the stove by emptying the drawer and removing grills and lift the corner with a prybar?  use a block of wood perhaps to prevent the prybar from marring something?

Comment: It was too heavy empty at 350lbs for me - I think the prybar is a good idea, unfortunately I don't have a prybar - just this bottle jack lol

Comment: Will be faster to go and get a prybar than trying to rig up something to use a bottle jack.  About best use of bottle jack is to place it on it's side and slip a piece of wood under stove, and use jack as a fulcrum.

Comment: Ok, I should just order a prbyar from Amazon it seems

Comment: A piece of 1x3 or 1x4 will work also.  Place it under stove and over bottle jack lying on it's side.  Push down on far end(3 or 4 ft.) of wood.

Comment: I have plenty of bad experience trying to lever heavy appliances up from underneath, and zero success stories.  What you usually have down there is that the only components capable of supporting weight are behind flimsy skirting so you can't lever anything without wrecking that.

Comment: Make sure you read the manual to find and avoid the "no lift" zones underneath. Or you'll end up crumpling the thing badly. Also, you need a toe-jack, not a bottle jack. (Or, really, just get some friends and a prybar.)

Comment: A lever a fulcrum, and set the bottle jack on the end of the lever (if you have enough leverage, the weight of the bottle jack will lift the stove - mission accomplished! ;^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An air wedge should do the trick, but you must check the bottom of the appliance can take the weight.

[image]

Comment: oh yeah this would make it really easy.

Answer (score 2):

In order of decreasing likelihood of success:

1. Wrangle a couple of friends, order pizza, have friends help lift the stove, have small child wriggle between the legs and put the floor protector disk in place. Feed everyone some pizza and possibly some adult beverages (if that's your thing) for the adults, and youth beverages for the youth.
2. Use a long "spud bar" (I have one that's 6' long) or a long pry bar (3' or so). Find *something solid* under the stove that will take weight (avoid trim, thin vertical side panels, etc). Use a block of wood as a fulcrum to lift the stove corner. Have a helper place the floor protector under the stove. Feed the helper some pizza & a beverage.
3. Weld together a steel frame to fit inside the oven. Put a steel plate on top of the frame. Weld a vertical framework that the platform will attach to at the door of the oven (with diagonal bracing reaching to the inside back of the oven). Place the bottle jack underneath the steel framework. Lift the stove (the framework will spread the weight across the flat plate against the roof of the oven, minimizing damage, unless there's an electric heating element there - remove if necessary). Insert floor protection disk. Lower the stove. Do *something* with all that extra steel. No pizza necessary for helpers because no helpers needed (except, perhaps, for moving the lifting framework into place - feed as desired).

Yes, that last one is somewhat facetious. However, I think that's the only reasonable way you'll be able to use the bottle jack to lift the stove without damaging the stove.

Comment: yeah having lots of people over is probably easiest - but just not now with this covid thing... soon enough I suppose when the vaccines catch up.

Comment: Caution is certainly warranted. But keep in mind that (at least in most of the USA) even from day 1 of the most severe restrictions (restaurants closed, gyms closed, all "non-essential" retail closed, schools closed), plumbers, electricians and other home repair has been considered "essential" and allowed. IMHO, paying a couple of friends in pizza is no different from paying a pro. The only difference from "normal" is you sit 6' apart outside when eating the pizza. Plus the entire repair process is pretty quick - you won't be next to each other for very long.

Comment: So long as nobody is diabetic, there's very little likely long-term harm anyway. Someone _might_ feel like they've got flu for a week, but, well, the _vast_ majority of people live through the flu, too.

Comment: @FreeMan The vast majority of people except for high risk (elderly, diabetic, etc. - who are exactly the people least likely to help with something like this anyway) do recover just fine. **But getting the flu for a week is not worth it to help a friend lift a stove.** It is all a matter of balancing risk vs. reward - if everyone starts off reasonably healthy (but can always be at beginning stages asymptomatic - so no absolute guarantee) and takes reasonable precautions (stay apart except when you are doing the actual work) the risk is minimal. I had the flu real bad once - not a fun week.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have the model number for your range, but I looked up the owners manual (listed below) for the AGA Mercury. According to the manual, you have casters on the back of that range. You can get two people or even one to lift the range and a third to slide the cup into place.

[image: how to lift range]

Naturally, I recommend verifying this is the right model and model number before you give this a shot.

Good luck.

- https://agarangeusa.com/file/68/AGA%20Mercury%2048in%20Dual%20Fuel%20-%20Owners%20Guide.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Remove the warming drawer, inspect its ceiling near opening to see if strong and rigid to take weight, find a large area where you can apply some upward pressure, put a block on the floor as fulcrum, use a larger piece of lumber as lever, insert a block of wood between lever and ceiling and carefully heave just enough to fit disc.

350lbs with a lifted side is only half that amount on the lever, and with a 4:1 lever (easily done) you're only pressing 45lbs. For the lever you could use a 2x4 even on the flat, or you might be able to use a wooden broom stick. Just try a few things carefully.